# triangles in hyperbolic geometry

Tags: geometry

I have to prove  which of the following is true: (1) DC = AB,(2) DC < AB, or (3) DC > AB (all hyperbolic length).

The only thing that im not sure about is whether vertical angles would work here. If it did then m∠ AEB=m∠ DEC. Then by AAA congruence we get that triangle DEC and triangle AEB are congruent. So DC=AB? Not sure if I did do it right.

[image]

Comment: Are $AEC$ and $BED$ assumed to be straight lines?

Comment: Locally, hyperbolic space looks like Euclidean space.  So points do have 360 degrees around them, lines have 180 degrees on each side of them, etc., and in particular you can use the fact that opposite angles of crossing geodesics are congruent.

Comment: i figured thanks

Answer (score 2):

Vertical angles do indeed have the same measure in hyperbolic geometry, and your work looks correct to me.

Answer (score 1):

You are ok. You see, there is no such thing as similarity in Hyperbolic Geometry. And so these isosceles triangles have the same anglesum (vertical angle theorem holds true) and therefore they have the same AREA. I am sure you know about angle defect and its relation to the triangle's area. Hence the triangles are congruent.